# Cannot satistfy dependency

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have an `eclipse plugin` which I am building into a fully `eclipse product` with `Maven Tycho`.

Manually building the `.target` definition of the product, I get some errors:

> [ERROR]   Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>   [org.eclipse.equinox.app 1.3.300.v20150423-1356,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app 1.3.400.v20150715-1528] [ERROR]   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: PLUGIN.id 1.1.1.2 depends on:
>   org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group 0.0.0 [ERROR]   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency: PLUGIN.id 1.1.1.2 depends on:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.sdk.feature.group
>   [3.11.0.v20150430-1834] [ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group 1.6.3.v20180214-0345 depends on:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app [1.3.400.v20150715-1528] [ERROR]   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.sdk.feature.group
>   3.11.0.v20150430-1834 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.app [1.3.300.v20150423-1356]

What can I do to solve the conflict from external plugins? Use two versions of plugins which use the same `org.eclipse.equinox.app` to remove the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing plug-in and product dependencies, but it looks like you have two deps declared for PLUGIN.id 1.1.1.2:

- org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.sdk [3.11.0.v20150430-1834]
- org.eclipse.e4.rcp

First is declared with version 3.11.0.v20150430-1834 and second declared without version. Without long explanation I would suggest to remove version from first and let eclipse deal with it.

Comment: As I stated, the plug-ins are external and I can't update their dependencies. I managed to fix the problem by using two plugins versions which were requiring the same `org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.sdk` version.